# Zlib crc32 combine endian format

Tags: crc32

I just go through the code of Zlib CRC32 combine function, but I am confused about the endian of the CRC32 input. Does it only work for big endian ? If I have small endian format, should I do a byte swap first before I use the function ? Thanks in advance.

```
/* ========================================================================= */
local uLong crc32_combine_(crc1, crc2, len2)
uLong crc1;
uLong crc2;
z_off64_t len2;
{
int n;
unsigned long row;
unsigned long even[GF2_DIM];    /* even-power-of-two zeros operator */
unsigned long odd[GF2_DIM];     /* odd-power-of-two zeros operator */

/* degenerate case (also disallow negative lengths) */
if (len2 <= 0)
    return crc1;

/* put operator for one zero bit in odd */
odd[0] = 0xedb88320UL;          /* CRC-32 polynomial */
row = 1;
for (n = 1; n < GF2_DIM; n++) {
    odd[n] = row;
    row <<= 1;
}

/* put operator for two zero bits in even */
gf2_matrix_square(even, odd);

/* put operator for four zero bits in odd */
gf2_matrix_square(odd, even);

/* apply len2 zeros to crc1 (first square will put the operator for one
   zero byte, eight zero bits, in even) */
do {
    /* apply zeros operator for this bit of len2 */
    gf2_matrix_square(even, odd);
    if (len2 & 1)
        crc1 = gf2_matrix_times(even, crc1);
    len2 >>= 1;

    /* if no more bits set, then done */
    if (len2 == 0)
        break;

    /* another iteration of the loop with odd and even swapped */
    gf2_matrix_square(odd, even);
    if (len2 & 1)
        crc1 = gf2_matrix_times(odd, crc1);
    len2 >>= 1;

    /* if no more bits set, then done */
} while (len2 != 0);

/* return combined crc */
crc1 ^= crc2;
return crc1;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of zlib works in little or big endian architectures.

There is no "endianess" of the arguments of `crc32_combine()`. The `crc1` and `crc2` arguments are passed as 32-bit integers, not sequences of bytes, and so have no endianess.

By the way, [there is more recent code for `crc32_combine()`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/develop/crc32.c#L1070) that is little bit more efficient.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer. If you don't mind, can I ask one more follow-up question ? From your experience, is multi-threading can help to speed-up CRC computation by compute partial CRC then recombine them at the end ? I am not sure if the overhead for multi-threading worth it but I am writing code to find out & want to hear the answer beforehand :).

Comment: Certainly. pigz does that.

Comment: @MarkAdler - You mentioned in another thread that zlib combine now implements combine by multiplying by 2^n (mod polynomial) instead of using the matrix method shown in the OP's question.